# Iframe url question for the experts

Tags: javascript, iframe

I was hoping that someone can help me, I am trying to get the URL of a page in a iframe:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function myLocation() {
        alert(document.all.myFrame.contentWindow.location);
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myLocation();">Location of Frame</button>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"
                              scrolling="auto" name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

This basically will give me the location of the iframe in my page, but does not give me the google.com url - it is also important to give me the url of everypage that I may open from the google results, so when I am on google.com it should give me the google.com url and if I browse to www.facebook.com it should give me the facebook url...

Any ideas welcome! Thanks

Comment: Please try to edit your question title to describe more whats the question about.

Comment: As a general recommendation, I would advise you to 1) change **deprecated** `language="JavaScript"` to **required** type="text/javascript". 2) Not to use non-standard `document.all`; instead, access form via `document.forms.myFrame`. 3) only insert that "onclick" button with JS, since it's useless and confusing when JS is off.

Comment: David's answer is right, it is very deliberate that you aren't allowed to do this. On an unrelated note, ‘contentWindow’ is a non-standard IE extension. In general you should use the standard ‘contentDocument’ property, falling back to ‘contentWindow’ when that isn't available (IE before version 8). To get from document to window if you have to you can use ‘contentDocument.defaultView’ — it isn't quite standardised that the view is the same as the window, but in every browser that supports it today, it is.

Comment: @bobince "Every browser" is a very dangerous statement :) I know at least one where `document.defaultView !== window` (it's Safari 2.0.2). I've also heard about IceBrowser doing same thing (but have never tried that browser myself). It's too bad MDC mixes two in its `getComputedStyle` article.

Answer (score 3):

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents accessing details (including the current URI) of documents on other domains.

If you want to work around this, you will either need to use something other than a web page (such as a standalone application or browser extension) or proxy all requests through your own server.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use some sort of javascript library, but i've tried this code on deviantart.com using raw javascript code:

`document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src` and it gave me the result i was expecting.

Comment: This only gives the src of the initial page. It doesn't update when the document changes.